# Save locale settings after restart the app using shared prefrences

Tags: android, android-activity

I am having the language settings  in my App itself only ... So I have Done Multilingual functionality using Locale it works Fine but now I got the Issue Like every Time i need to set the Language When App restarts  so i need to save it for only once Can any one suggest me on this Issue....

```
// Shared Preferences for Storing Spinner Selected position


    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Mypreference", 0);
    ((Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.sp_countries)).setSelection(pref
            .getInt("country", 0));
    ((Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.sp_language)).setSelection(pref
            .getInt("language", 0));
    ((Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.sp_currency)).setSelection(pref
            .getInt("currency", 0));
    ((Spinner) this.findViewById(R.id.sp_serviceprovider))
            .setSelection(pref.getInt("serviceprovider", 0));
```

// On Button click I Am Saving the Shared preference Values

```
    tv_finish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor_ab = AboutActivity.this
                    .getSharedPreferences("Mypreference", 0).edit();
            editor_ab.putInt("country", ((Spinner) AboutActivity.this
                    .findViewById(R.id.sp_countries))
                    .getSelectedItemPosition());
            editor_ab.putInt("language", ((Spinner) AboutActivity.this
                    .findViewById(R.id.sp_language))
                    .getSelectedItemPosition());
            editor_ab.putInt("currency", ((Spinner) AboutActivity.this
                    .findViewById(R.id.sp_currency))
                    .getSelectedItemPosition());
            editor_ab.putInt("serviceprovider",
                    ((Spinner) AboutActivity.this
                            .findViewById(R.id.sp_serviceprovider))
                            .getSelectedItemPosition());

            // editor_ab.commit();
            editor_ab.putString("Lang", lang);
            editor_ab.commit();

            prefs.edit().putString("Lang", lang).commit();

            // prefs.edit().putString("lang", lang).commit();

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    CardSale_Activity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // finish();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Saved Successfully",
                    1000).show();
        }

    });

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
        long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String sp1 = String.valueOf(Spinner_Country.getSelectedItem());

    if (sp1.contentEquals("India")) {
        List<String> listIn = new ArrayList<String>();
        listIn.add("English");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterIn = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listIn);
        dataAdapterIn
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapterIn.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Spinner_Language.setAdapter(dataAdapterIn);

        List<String> listIn2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        listIn2.add("Rupee");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterIn2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listIn2);
        dataAdapterIn2
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapterIn2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Spinner_Currency.setAdapter(dataAdapterIn2);

        setLocale("lang");

    }
    if (sp1.contentEquals("France")) {
        List<String> listFr = new ArrayList<String>();
        listFr.add("French");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterFr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listFr);
        dataAdapterFr
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapterFr.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Spinner_Language.setAdapter(dataAdapterFr);

        List<String> listFr2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        listFr2.add("Euro");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterFr2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listFr2);
        dataAdapterFr2
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapterFr2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Spinner_Currency.setAdapter(dataAdapterFr2);

        setLocale("fr");

    }

    if (sp1.contentEquals("Nigeria")) {
        List<String> listNg = new ArrayList<String>();
        listNg.add("English");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterFr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listNg);
        dataAdapterFr
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapterFr.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Spinner_Language.setAdapter(dataAdapterFr);

        List<String> listNg2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        listNg2.add("Naira");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterFr2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listNg2);
        dataAdapterFr2
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapterFr2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Spinner_Currency.setAdapter(dataAdapterFr2);

        setLocale("ng");

    }

    if (sp1.contentEquals("Kenya")) {
        List<String> listKe = new ArrayList<String>();
        listKe.add("English");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterFr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listKe);
        dataAdapterFr
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapterFr.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Spinner_Language.setAdapter(dataAdapterFr);

        List<String> listKe2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        listKe2.add("Kenya");
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterFr2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, listKe2);
        dataAdapterFr2
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        dataAdapterFr2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Spinner_Currency.setAdapter(dataAdapterFr2);

        setLocale("ke");

    }

}

public void setLocale(String lang) {

    Locale myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    Resources res = getResources();
    DisplayMetrics dm = res.getDisplayMetrics();
    Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources()
            .getConfiguration();
    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
    Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();
    config.locale = myLocale;
    res.updateConfiguration(config, dm);
    onConfigurationChanged(conf);
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
            getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    lang = prefs.getString("Lang", lang);

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Mypreference", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor_ab = pref.edit();
    editor_ab.putString("Lang", lang);
    editor_ab.commit();
}

/**
 * onRestart Called after your activity has been stopped, prior to it being
 * started again. Always followed by onStart().
 * 
 */

protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();

    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("Mypreference", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor_ab = pref.edit();
    editor_ab.putString("Lang", lang);
    editor_ab.commit();

    prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    lang = prefs.getString("Lang", lang);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    Intent i_settingsback = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i_settingsback);
    AboutActivity.this.finish();

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void loadLocale()
{
    String langPref = "Language";
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String language = prefs.getString(langPref, "");
    changeLang(language);
}

public void saveLocale(String lang)
{
    String langPref = "Language";
    SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("CommonPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(langPref, lang);
    editor.commit();
}

public void changeLang(String lang)
{
    if (lang.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
        return;
    myLocale = new Locale(lang);
    saveLocale(lang);
    Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
    android.content.res.Configuration config = new android.content.res.Configuration();
    config.locale = myLocale;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    updateTexts();
}
```

In updateTexts() you can call setText() for all the elements that need language change setting string as "R.string.my_string" which will have a translation

Call loadLocale() in onResume() and onCreate()

changeLang() should be called when you want to change the language

You can also handle config changes

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(android.content.res.Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (myLocale != null){
        newConfig.locale = myLocale;
        Locale.setDefault(myLocale);
        getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(newConfig, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Pratik Borole Thanks For Guiding me... but The ISsue Is Not Cleared the Selected Values are Saved But Language is Not Saving and Language is not changed in All Activities Too...First I Will Explain My requirement

Comment: 1.I am Having four Spinners Country,Currency,Language,Based On The Country Entire App Language Will Changed On button Click                                            2.Its Not A Luncher Activity ..                                                                        3

Comment: To change the language in a particular activity, define loadLocale() and call it in onCreate()

Also, in updateText(), you'll have to load the string from your strings.xml
According to the language that is set, the app will automatically pick up the translation (only if it exists). Which means you'll have to give translation for all the strings used in your app.

Comment: While calling changeLang() use the ISO 639-1 codes [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-2_codes)

Something like changeLang("en") for English or changeLang("fr") for French